# Display the resources of the native memory of web page

Tags: google-chrome, memory

Chrome dev tools can only show the javascript heap memory. I use `process memory - heap memory` to estimate the total mount of native memory. I wonder if there is a tool to display how much memory is allocated by which kind of resource?